# Perl Mojolicious: limit concurrency with all_settled

Tags: perl, async-await, promise, mojolicious

In [Mojolicious](https://docs.mojolicious.org/) for Perl, is there a way to limit [`concurrency`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Promise#map) when using [`Promise->all_settled`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Promise#all_settled)?

In the example below, I would like to limit `concurrency=>10`. I'm using `sleep` to simulate a blocking operation:

```perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures, -async_await;

helper isOdd_p => sub($self, $number)
{
    return Mojo::Promise->new(sub($resolve, $reject ) {
        Mojo::IOLoop->subprocess(
            sub {
                sleep 1;
                $number % 2;
            },
            sub ($subprocess, $err, @res ) {
                $reject->( $err ) if $err;
                $reject->( @res ) if @res && $res[0]==0; # reject Even
                $resolve->( @res );
            })
            
        });
};

any '/' => async sub ($c) {
    $c->render_later();
    my @promises = map { $c->isOdd_p($_) } (0..50);
    my @results = eval { await Mojo::Promise->all_settled(@promises) };
    #my @results = eval { await Mojo::Promise->map({concurrency=>10}, sub { $c->isOdd_p($_)}, (0..50) ) };
    if (my $err = $@) {
        $c->render(json => $@); # will this line be ever reached with all_settled??
    } else {
        $c->render(json => [ @results ] );
    }
};

app->start;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, you start all 51 tasks, then wait for all 51 tasks to finish.

Limiting concurrency to 10 would mean starting 10 tasks, waiting for one to finish, starting one, waiting for one to finish, etc.

Three tiny changes to `map` suffices. (Changed two mentions of `all` to `all_settled`, and changed the rejection handler to keep going. Also changed it from a M::P method to a sub.)

```perl
sub map_all_settled {
  my ($class, $options, $cb, @items) = ('Mojo::Promise', ref $_[0] eq 'HASH' ? shift : {}, @_);
 
  return $class->all_settled(map { $_->$cb } @items) if !$options->{concurrency} || @items <= $options->{concurrency};
 
  my @start = map { $_->$cb } splice @items, 0, $options->{concurrency};
  my @wait  = map { $start[0]->clone } 0 .. $#items;
 
  my $start_next = sub {
    return () unless my $item = shift @items;
    my ($start_next, $chain) = (__SUB__, shift @wait);
    $_->$cb->then(sub { $chain->resolve(@_); $start_next->() }, sub { $chain->reject(@_); $start_next->() }) for $item;
    return ();
  };
 
  $_->then($start_next, sub { }) for @start;
 
  return $class->all_settled(@start, @wait);
}
```

```perl
my @results = await map_all_settled({concurrency=>10}, sub { $c->isOdd_p($_)}, (0..50) );
```

Comment: Small clarification. How do I extend `Mojo::Promise` to add `map_all_settled`?

Comment: Well, you could add it to the namespace. But there's no reason to do that. I just forgot to rename it. (Was very tired.)